# Can't access node from puppet dashboard

Tags: ubuntu, puppet, puppet-dashboard

I am trying to setup puppet's dashboard to be monitor the status of my servers. With the below shown configurations, my clients (or nodes) only show up as *Unreported* and says `Has not reported` in "Last report".

However the node  can communicate with the server and pull changes as it's supposed to, but nothing appears in the dash. I have followed [these docs](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/dashboard/index.html) trying to set it up, but I have no idea of what I am doing wrong.

Have I missed anything obvious?

```
// Server /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
[master]
reports = store,http
reporturl = http://192.168.1.101:3000/reports/upload

// Client /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
[agent]
report = true
```

Comment: What version of puppet are you running?  And what is your `reportdir` set to?  Does your `reportdir` contain reports?

Answer (score 4):

It was not clear to me that I had to also add workers to process my incoming reports. By doing this I've managed to get it all working:

```
env RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job -p dashboard -n 4 -m start
```

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/dashboard/manual/1.2/bootstrapping.html

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful.  I had to `cd /usr/share/puppet-dashboard` before running that command.

Answer (score 1):

Puppet now has a daemon associated with this task, which is found at

/etc/init.d/puppet-dashboard-workers

on redhat-like linux systems, which run the background processes that handle the incoming reports.